# Terminal appears with much delay when shortcut is used

Tags: gnome-terminal, shortcuts

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> the Terminal opens after around 30 seconds. That's pretty annoying.
If I open it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gnome-terminal` the window appears instantly as usual.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with gnome3.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Maybe look in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Launchers -> Launch Terminal, and check that it's set correctly. Have you made any changes to your keyboard shortcuts recently?

Comment: It's set correctly and I haven't done any canges.

Comment: @AlexLeidwein, There is now a solution available versus just a workaround.  Remove dbus-user-session which is not installed by default in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gnome keyring daemon not starting up properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898694/gnome-keyring-daemon-not-starting-up-properly)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Temporary workaround discussed in comment 16
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=729101#c16

run `gnome-keyring-daemon` in terminal with no command line options.
Then everything works as normal after entering password to unlock keyring.

On my system I have to open HUD before the password prompt shows up. If I open the HUD before the terminal command, the password prompt dialog shows immediately.

Output of `journalctl -f` shows
`gnome-keyring-daemon[12913]: Gkm: using old keyring directory: ...`

**Now Solved:**
For me and many others the solution to this issue has been to remove `dbus-user-session` which was added along with a recent install of software that is not needed.  For me, it was added when I installed `flatpak`

Solution:

1. `sudo apt-get remove --purge dbus-user-session`
2. Reboot

More context is available starting at comment #67 in this thread.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1689825

Comment: This should be the top voted and accepted answer as it contains a real fix and not just a dirty workaround of killing the `gnome-keyring-daemon`, which will make the saved passwords etc. unavailable IIRC.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Also fixed too similar problems I had: delay between pressing "Print Screen" and the screenshot being taken, and Google Chrome being slow to first launch.

Comment: Ran into this after deliberately installing `dbus-user-session` in order to support systemd services that raise notifiers over dbus. This is presumably some misconfiguration where the systemd user session isn't actually the same as the GUI session.

Answer (score 13):

Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/742914/slow-hotkey-response-in-gnome-3-12) on superuser:

> From the [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=729101) filed by [xgdgsc](https://superuser.com/questions/742914/slow-hotkey-response-in-gnome-3-12#comment963562_742914), this slow response to GNOME shortcuts appears to be caused by `gnome-keyring-daemon`. In particular, having multiple instances of the daemon appears to cause shortcut execution to pause while attempting to communicate with the daemon until it times out. You can use the following command to check if you have multiple instances of the daemon running:
>
> ```sh
> pgrep gnome-keyring --list-full
> ```
>
> On CentOS 7 with GNOME 3.14.2, I was able to work around this by killing both processes:
>
> ```sh
> killall gnome-keyring-daemon
> ```
>
> `gnome-keyring-daemon` automatically restarted with only one instance when I next used a GNOME keyboard shortcut, and the shortcut executed instantaneously.

Comment: Even with only one gnome-keyring running, I'm still getting slow response when opening terminals.  When I killed all `gnome-keyring-daemon` Chrome was not able to login.

Comment: @AntoniosHadjigeorgalis on my experience, this type of delay happening just for one or two shortcuts. If `killall gnome-keyring-daemon` not working for you, maybe reassigning those shortcuts can help.

Comment: @ICE new shortcuts did not work either.

Answer (score 7):

Open Startup Application and add new

1. Add new
2. Name : whatever
3. Command : `killall gnome-keyring-daemon`
4. Comment : whatever

enjoy..

Comment: What does `terserah` supposed to mean?

Comment: @Anwar: "terserah" is an Indonesian/Malay word for "whatever" or "anything". The name and description of start up application is only there to help you find and organize it, but it doesn't really matter what you put in there. Maybe SierraX copied it from some blog/site somewhere and forget to translate it?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this helped me. Went to  System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Launchers -> Launch Terminal
there was written something new accelerator. I reset the key by hold pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> again.
it solved the problem.