# Ubuntu Unity 16.04 Ctrl-Alt-T spawns terminal with lag

Tags: 16.04, unity, launcher, gnome-terminal

I recently met an issue with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. It launches a terminal with sufficient lag, approximately 30-40 seconds. Terminal starts almost instantly from dash. Any tips to resolve? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check on Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts whats the *command* associated to Ctrl+Alt+T ?

Comment: Under Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Launchers: "Launch terminal" -> Ctrl-Alt-T.

Comment: Do other keyboard shortcuts also lag?

Comment: No. After some experiments, the picture is following:  Ctrl-Alt-T attached to "launch email client" starts Thunderbird instantly. Creating custom shortcut Ctrl-Alt-T to start gnome-terminal - starts with same lag (~30 sec). Locking gnome-terminal to launcher and starting with Super-2 - starts instantly :)

Comment: The fix suggested here worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/911946/terminal-shortcut-delayed

Comment: Awesome! Killing gnome-keyring-daemon solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, got it working by altering entry "SSH Key Agent" in Startup Applications to "/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --replace --foreground --components=ssh"

The discussion is here https://plus.google.com/+SamXu/posts/WNCf3cirGUG