# Error while trying to store LUKS HDD passphrase in key wallet

Tags: mount, hard-drive, encryption, luks, gnome-keyring

I have a LUKS encrypted external hard-drive (full partition encrypted). While mounting the media, I enter the passphrase in the prompt and I check the "remember the password forever" option.

The media opens after a few seconds and is correctly decrypted, but later I get this error (translated from French) in a window :

```
Impossible to mount 2 TB volume :
Error while storing the passphrase into the key wallet (Error in the call of StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.secrets : Timeout was reached)
```

Obviously the passphrase is not stored and I have to enter it again the next time I try to mount the HDD. The HDD is yet perfectly usable (read/write).

A few weeks ago, I deleted some useless librairies with an optimization software to spare some space on the root. This problem showed up afterwards. I tried to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` and all its recommended packages, but it did not solve the problem. I reinstalled `pam` and `libpam-mount` as well, but no success so far.

Comment: I found the solution here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/911946/terminal-appears-with-much-delay-when-shortcut-is-used